# Internal SSD Drive drops randomly until restart

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

I hope this is the correct place to ask this.

I am on a ROG Zephyrus G15 running windows 11 that has two SATA ports that I use. One is the system drive that came pre-installed on my device, and the other is a storage drive I purchased. This secondary drive is where my problem lies. Occasionally (about once a day), the had drive will disappear from my computer without leaving a trace(not in file explorer, disk management, or device manager). However, as soon as I restart my computer it shows up again just like normal.

I have previously had this issue and solved it by setting "Turn Off Hard Dive" under power plan settings to "never". I have since performed a clean reboot of my computer and this problem has return, only this time the previous solution is not working. I have looked in many places for a fix to this problem, but the solutions presented elsewhere do not work for me.

I have scanned my disk for problems many times, but it always says the disk is completely good. I have backed up my data and reformatted the disk to no avail as well. I have removed it and reinstalled it to check for connectivity issues as well (though the fact I get the drive back on a normal restart leads me to think this is not an issue). All drivers and OS up to date.

To be honest, I have no clue where to go from here to solve the problem and was hoping somebody might have an idea.

A couple of guesses and info that I am not sure is totally relevant I have (not confirmed) are that this is happing after the computer sleeps. I have manually put it to sleep and woken it up with the drive still being there, but is seems to usually be missing after the computer has been sleeping for a while. I have also found in the event viewer the warning "Disk 0 has been surprise removed", though info/help relating to this has been slim and unhelpful. Not sure if any of this is useful, and happy to provide any more info that might be needed. Would really appreciate any thoughts/suggestions. Thanks.